# Why i can't to display my string value after assign number to it?

Tags: c++, string, display

i want to get all numbers from my string and after it push them to vector but before this i want to display value of my  "string number" to check effects, the problem is than i don't see it.

```
string napis = "ada87dasu3da1";

    string number = "";
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < napis.size(); i++){
        if(isdigit(napis[i]) == true){
            number[counter] = (char)napis[i];
            counter++;
        }else if(isdigit(napis[i]) == false && isdigit(napis[i-1]) == true)
            cout << number;       // <- there is a problem
            counter = 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're indexing `number` at invalid positions. It has size 0, so you can't index it at all. You could try `push_back`.

Comment: i fixed it still not working

Comment: `cout` may be line buffered, so `cout << number` won't print anything until an end-of-line is output (which you never do), or the buffer fills up (which it probably doesn't), or the program ends.  Try `cout << number << flush`, or `cout << number << endl` to have more readable output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number[i] = ...` does not *append* a new character, like you are expecting it to.  It *modifies* an existing character at a given index, but there are no characters to modify because `number` is always empty!  You are not doing anything to increase its `size()`.

You need to use the string's `push_back()` or `operator+=` instead:

```
number.push_back(napis[i]);
```

```
number += napis[i];
```

---

Also, `isdigit(napis[i-1])` goes out of bounds when `i` is 0, which is the case in your example since the 1st character of `napis` is not a digit.  You don't need to check `isdigit()` in your `else` at all.  And you don't need the `counter`, either.

Try this instead:

```
string napis = "ada87dasu3da1";
string number;

for(size_t i = 0; i < napis.size(); ++i){
    if (isdigit(napis[i]){
        number += napis[i];
    }
    else if (!number.empty()) {
        cout << number << flush;
        number.clear();
    }
}

if (!number.empty()){
    cout << number << flush;
}
```

That being said, there are other ways you can write this, that do not require you to check and append every individual character manually, for instance:

```
const char *digits = "0123456789";

string napis = "ada87dasu3da1";
string number;

string::size_type start = napis.find_first_of(digits);
while (start != string::npos) {
    string::size_type end = napis.find_first_not_of(digits, start + 1);
    if (end == string::npos) {
        number = napis.substr(start);
        start = napis.size();
    }
    else {
        number = napis.substr(start, end - start);
        start = end + 1;
    }
    cout << number << flush;
    start = napis.find_first_of(digits, start);
}
```